# How do I grant local administrator rights, but not Domain Administrator Rights?

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2003, permissions

How do I grant local administrator rights, but not Domain Administrator Rights?

i.e.

For user x, I want to grant install rights on the computer, but the user should not have Domain admin rights as I have a bunch of folders which are accessible only to administrators and not Domain users.

Server OS: Windows Server 2003
User OS: Windows 7

Comment: If we add them to the Administrators group on the computer in question, through the local users MMC snap-in, does the user get rights to add other domain users as admin on that machine ? Assuming the user is a domain user...

Answer (score 2):

You add them to the `Administrators` group on the computer in question, through the local users MMC snap-in.

Answer (score 1):

If it's only a handful of computers, you can simply add the user to the local group `Administrators` on each client.

If you want to enforce this on a larger scale, you should employ Group Policies. In that case you can use `Restricted Groups` under Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings.